# Slow SQL Query, how to improve this query speed?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (call_history) with a list of phone calls report, caller_id is the caller and start_date (DATETIME) is the call date. I need to make a report that will show how many people called for the first time for every day. For example:

```
2013-01-01 - 100
2013-01-02 - 80
2013-01-03 - 90
```

I have this query that does it perfectly, but it is very slow. There are indexes on both start_date and caller_id columns; is there an alternative way to get this information to speed the process up?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(c1.start_date,1,10), COUNT(DISTINCT caller_id)
FROM call_history c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT id
 FROM call_history c2
 WHERE SUBSTR(c2.start_date,1,10) < SUBSTR(c1.start_date,1,10) 
   AND c2.caller_id=c1.caller_id)
GROUP BY SUBSTR(start_date,1,10)
ORDER BY  SUBSTR(start_date,1,10) desc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following "WHERE SUBSTR(c2.start_date,1,10)" is breaking your index (you shouldn't perform functions on the left hand side of a where clause)

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT DATE(c1.start_date), COUNT(caller_id) 
FROM call_history c1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN call_history c2 on c1.caller_id = c2.caller_id and c2.start_date < c1.start_date 
where c2.id is null 
GROUP BY DATE(start_date) 
ORDER BY start_date desc
```

Also re-reading your problem, I think this is another way of writing without using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT DATE(c1.start_date), COUNT(DISTINCT c1.caller_id) 
FROM call_history c1 
where start_date = 
    (select min(start_date) from call_history c2 where c2.caller_id = c1.caller_id) 
GROUP BY DATE(start_date) 
ORDER BY c1.start_date desc;
```

Comment: changing the "ORDER BY SUBSTR(start_date,1,10)" to "ORDER BY start_date DESC" making it run 2 times faster, everything else making it slower,

Comment: the 2nd query suggestion actually takes 2 times more time than the original one

Comment: ok. what is the output of running this:EXPLAIN SELECT DATE(c1.start_date), COUNT(DISTINCT caller_id)
FROM call_history c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT id
 FROM call_history c2
 WHERE c2.start_date < DATE(c1.start_date) 
   AND c2.caller_id=c1.caller_id)
GROUP BY DATE(start_date)
ORDER BY start_date desc

Comment: it is very true that using substr(c1.start_date, 1, 10) is not letting you use the index.... you can do two things... either remove substr(....) OR create a new index using substr(start_date, 1, 10) see if that works.

Comment: using DATE(c1.start_date) and SUBSTR(...) is not effecting the query speed, only removing this from the ORDER BY helped it, but not by much, here is the output:
id select_type   table type possible_keys   key   key_len  ref       rows Extra
1 PRIMARY    c1  ALL  NULL     NULL  NULL  NULL      9087 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY c2  ref  caller_id,start_date caller_id  22   trivia_ivr.c1.caller_id  3  Using where

Comment: and the output of this sql command?: desc call_history.
Might as well try changing subquery to outer join: 
SELECT DATE(c1.start_date), COUNT(caller_id)
FROM call_history c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN call_history c2
on c1.caller_id = c2.caller_id and c2.start_date < c1.start_date
where c2.id is null
GROUP BY DATE(start_date)
ORDER BY start_date desc

Comment: here is the desc call_history:
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| event_id   | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| caller_id  | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| uniqueid   | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| duration   | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_date | datetime    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| from_did   | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |

Comment: the last query is actually much faster, we're now at 0.17 speed, while the original one was around 1 second.

Comment: you seem to have every column indexed, evaluate whether you really need every column indexed as it does come at a cost when building and maintaining during CRUD operations on that table. anyway 0.17 is pretty fast.

Comment: They are all indexed as I'm searching for data in all of them,
I'm currently working on 9000 rows, i'm worried that once I'll have 100,000 and more rows it will take forever to execute, 
for now that will do tho, thanks!

Comment: FYI `NOT EXIST` Is faster using `POSTGRES` And `JOIN`'S are faster in `MySQL`

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a weird thing - using functions in `WHERE`, `GROUP` and `ORDER` clauses. MySQL **will never** use indexes when function was applied to calculate condition. So, you can not do anything with *this* query, but to improve your situation, you should alter your table structure and store your date as `DATE` column (and single column). Then create index by this column - after this you'll get much better results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the NOT EXISTS with a left outer join.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is the ideal solution,
speed is now 0.01

```
SELECT first_call_date, COUNT(caller_id) AS caller_count
FROM (
    SELECT caller_id, DATE(MIN(start_date)) AS first_call_date
    FROM call_history 
    GROUP BY caller_id
) AS ch
GROUP BY first_call_date
ORDER BY first_call_date DESC
```